# The method notifyDataSetChanged() not working in custom Listview

Tags: android

I custom listview with adapter extend BaseAdapter.
In method getView I have a button Add, and I set listener to it

```
item.btnAddBasket.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showChooseSize(products.get(pos), pos);
                DialogFragmentCustom.setPosition(pos);
            }
        });
```

And I have two method, which are call when I press button Add.

```
public void showChooseSize(ProductInfo productInfo, int pos) {
    ArrayList<Stock> stocks = new ArrayList<Stock>();
    stocks.addAll(productInfo.getStock());
    ArrayList<String> colors = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> sizes = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (stocks != null && stocks.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < stocks.size() - 1; i++) {
            colors.add(stocks.get(i).getColorName());
            sizes.add(stocks.get(i).getSize());
        }
    }
    if (sizes != null && sizes.size() > 0) {
        HashSet<String> hs_size = new HashSet<String>(); // remove elements
                                                            // duplicate
        hs_size.addAll(sizes);
        sizes.clear();
        sizes.addAll(hs_size);
        if (sizes.size() == 1) {
            size = sizes.get(0);
        } else {
            for (int j = 0; j < sizes.size() - 1; j++) {
                size = size + sizes.get(j) + ", ";
            }
            size = size + sizes.get(sizes.size() - 1);
        }
        a_sizes = null;
        if (size.split(",") != null) {
            a_sizes = size.split(",");
        }
        if (a_sizes == null) {
            a_sizes[0] = "This product do not have size";
        }
        if (a_sizes != null && a_sizes.length > 0) {
            Config.isWishList = true;
            ((Activity) context).setTheme(R.style.ActionSheetStyleIOS7);
            ActionSheetChooseSize.setProductInfo(productInfo);
            ActionSheetChooseSize.createBuilder(context, ((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager()).setOtherButtonTitles(a_sizes)
                    .setCancelableOnTouchOutside(true).setListener(this).show();

            isShowChooseSize = true;
        } else {
            addToBag(productInfo, pos);
        }
    }
```

Method add product into Bag when press button Add, it inside my adapter

```
public void addToBag(ProductInfo productInfo, int pos) {
    // Config.productSaleInfos.add(products.get(pos));
    Config.productSaleInfos.add(productInfo);
    Config.numProductSale = Config.productSaleInfos.size();
    Config.numProductWishlist = Config.numProductWishlist - 1 < 0 ? Config.numProductWishlist - 1 : 0;
    //SlideMenuFragment.setNumWish(Config.numProductWishlist + "");
    new DeletionItemWishlist(context).execute(products.get(pos));
    products.remove(pos);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    float sumaryPrice = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) {
        String price = products.get(i).getSalePrice();
        int index = price.indexOf(",");
        if (index > -1) {
            price = price.replace(",", "");
        }
        float p = Functions.getFloatFromString(price);
        sumaryPrice = sumaryPrice + p;
    }
    basket.setText(Config.numProductSale + "");
    subtotal.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Subtotal: </b>" + "<font color=\"#FF7F00\">" + sumaryPrice + " ฿</font>"));
    Functions.showLog(context, "add bag success!");
}
```

But notifyDataSetChanged(); is not working in my code. Can you help me please?

Comment: Is `addToBag` method is inside adapter?

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged isn't being called? Is throwing an error? What about it isn't working?

Comment: use notifyDataSetChanged(); in item.btnAddBasket.setOnClickListener and check

Comment: Yes,  ρяσѕρєя K, addToBag inside adapter

Comment: @Shaun Frisbee it not update my adapter

Comment: @user3676184 I did it, but it work difference my flow, which i want..when press add if a_sizes not null, it show dialog confirm. If Ok, the data in adapter will change